# Two returns doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I have html running javascript after form,

```
form name="mortgage" method="post" action=" "onsubmit="return completeFormValidation();">
```

And javascript code for validation,

mainFunction:

```
function completeFormValidation() {

return yearentry1();

return my_location();


} // End of completeFormValidation
```

1st function in main:

```
function yearentry1(){

     var yearval = document.mortgage.mortYear.value;
     alert(yearval);

}
```

2nd function in main:

```
function my_location(){

  var numradio = document.mortgage.propLocation.length;
  var selected="";

  for(var i=0; i < numradio; i++){

    if(document.mortgage.propLocation[i].checked == true){
        selected += "Selected radio item " + i;

    }
  }

  if(selected == ""){

    document.getElementById("reserved").innerHTML = "<p> none radio selected </P>";
    return false;

  }

}
```

returning two times doesn't seem to work! when 1st function passes and returns TRUE the
function quits and sends the form.

is it possible if i can have all functions run in the main function and then return false if any of the functions inside main returned false?

Comment: You need add a space in the form definition after `action=" "`.

Comment: Code after a return statement will never be executed, because, as you said, the first return will "quit the function".

Comment: This line `return my_location();` will never be executed, beacause the code will always return before in the `return my_yearentry();`

Comment: What would be the way to fix it! or any alternative to what I want to achieve!

Comment: What does `my_yearentry` return? Please show us the code for that.

Comment: You'd probably want to return an object of the two things: `return {'year_entry': my_yearentry(), 'location': my_location()};`

Comment: I guess the correct name for this function `yearentry1`  is `my_yearentry`

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. You can return an array, but I doubt that's necessary.

Comment: It's clear what you do and that surprises you but not what you want to achieve. Write it in your question.

Comment: If `yearentry1` is the same as `my_yearentry`, then there is no need for the first `return`, since that function doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: `return` is to end function and pass something to the parent function. When you call a function you can catch what it returns or just ignore it or return it to its own parent (and this is what you do here which looks pointless)

Comment: is it possible if i can have all functions run in the main function and then return false if any of the functions inside main returned false?

Comment: @Sobasofly: yes, although it's a bit awkward:  `return (fn1() !== false && fn2() !== false && fn3() !== false /* ... */);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you would like to only submit the form if both functions return false.  In that case, you would want the following:

```
function completeFormValidation() {

    return my_yearentry() && my_location();    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LgepA/1/

`&&` is "and".

In this case if the first function returns false, the 2nd won't even be executed.  If you want 2nd to always execute, you can use simply `&`:

```
function completeFormValidation(){

    return !!(my_yearentry() & my_location());   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LgepA/3/

Or in a more readable manner:

```
function completeFormValidation(){

    var yearResult = my_yearentry();
    var locationResult = my_location();

    return yearResult && locationResult;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LgepA/4/

Comment: I want the second function to run and then return false!

Comment: What i want is to have all the functions run and if any of them did return false after running all the functions it will return false and not submit!

Comment: Then use the 2nd approach I have listed.  Just ensure your functions actually have a return value.  Your first function (not the same name as the one being called) has no return at all.

Comment: it goes through all functions but it submits it at the end! when the function was false!

Comment: your second provided solution perfectly fine thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The "return" statement ends the function, so you can't call anything after this.

Wrong:

```
function completeFormValidation() {
    return my_yearentry();
    return my_location();
}
```

Correct:

```
function completeFormValidation() {
    return my_yearentry() && my_location();
}
```

But your my_yearentry function must have a boolean return value.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because neither of your other functions are ready, but ideally you would want to do something like:

```
function completeFormValidation() {
    return my_yearentry() && my_location();
}
```

The trouble is neither of the other functions always return something useful either.

If they both always returned (and ideally returned `true` or `false`) then this would work.

Perhaps

```
function yearentry1(){
    var yearval = document.mortgage.mortYear.value;
    return yearval;
}
```

and

```
function my_location(){
    if(selected == ""){
        document.getElementById("reserved").innerHTML = "<p> none radio selected </P>";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

although mixing together your validation checks and your validation reporting might also be problematic.  This could be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Once a function returns, that function call is finished.

```
function completeFormValidation() {

    my_yearentry(); // take away return statement, just call the function
                    // you have inconsistent function name below :"yearentry1()"

    return my_location();
}
```